# Getting pointer address and perform operations against them

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* npx;
};

struct Node* XOR (struct Node *a, struct Node *b)
{
    return (struct Node*) (a ^ b);
}
```

In above XOR function, 'a' and 'b' are pointers which means 'a' & 'b' should give address literally.

1. why it is failing with "invalid operands to binary ^" error?
2. what is the return value for simply using a. What if, uint32_t addr = a;

Comment: You cannot perform binary arithmetic on pointers (what would the resulting pointer even point to?)

Comment: Are you trying to make a xor linked list? Convert the pointers to `uintptr_t` first, and store the result as `uintptr_t` too.

Comment: @UnholySheep Maybe they're trying to make [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list)?

Comment: You will need to convert pointer to a corresponding integer type first.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat . Yes. What happens in background, when we used "uintptr_t" and not used?

Comment: @Kranthi Using `uintptr_t` shouldn't affect the generated code. It simply makes the compiler accept arbitrary arithmetic operations on your pointers.